# Continous rolling of images from top to bottom in a image control in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image

Good Morning. Image sliding from top to bottom is the known question only. But i tried with earlier answers, in that there is no continuity( when one image is sliding down another must enter from top ).

I tried with few slidings but not fruitful in continuity maintaining for a series of images in one image control only. As the work i have to prepate tick-tack kind game with 9 image controls individually sliding a series of images. When a image is selected sliding should stop and win conditions are horizontal or vertical or crosswise image equals.

Can someone help me with this. Thank you very much in advance.

Thanks,
Jagadeesh

Comment: One Image control can only show one image. For sliding one image in while another is sliding out, you'll need two Image controls in a common container.

Comment: Sir, as you said i have used two image controls in a container and tried to slide with BeginTime difference like following. But i need the continuous movement of a series of images. Presently after first image sliding second one with timegap scrolls, but i need to replace first image again while second is scrolling. How to do this i am not getting. Can you please help me.

Comment: <Storyboard x:Key="TestStoryboard">   <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Image1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)" 
Duration="0:0:0.5" FillBehavior="Stop"  AccelerationRatio=".1" From="0" To="200"/> 
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Image2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)" Duration="0:0:0.5" FillBehavior="Stop" BeginTime="0:0:0.5" AccelerationRatio=".05" From="0"  To="200" /> </Storyboard>

Comment: Please don't post code or XAML in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for your suggestion. Any idea to further proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer as for continuous rolling of images, two image controls in a container needs to be taken and with BeginTime difference they needs to be slided one by one and then with timer support this behaviour needs to be repeated. For not showing the images outside of image control borders, a scroll control needs to be attached to the container. If scroll control is not there while sliding they will appear above and below the borders of image control.